# Run python in a separate process

Tags: python, process

I'm looking for a quick bash script or program that will allow me to kick off a python script in a separate process.  What's the best way to do this?  I know this is incredibly simple, just curious if there's a preferred way to do it.

Comment: It appears that you mean "process".  Please update your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use the ampersand (&) in order to launch the Python process in the background. Python already is executed in a separate process from the BASH script, so saying to run it "in a separate thread" doesn't make much sense -- I'm assuming you simply want it to run in the background:

```
#! /bin/bash
python path/to/python/program.py &
```

Note that the above may result in text being printed to the console. You can get around this by using redirection to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file. For example:

```
#! /bin/bash
python path/to/python/program.py > results.txt 2> errors.log &
```

Comment: Where you say "stdin" I assume you mean "stderr" and it should be `2>errors.log` (without the ampersand after the "2").

Comment: Yah, this is what I was expecting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is to do it in python! Have a look at the [multiprocess libraries](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Here is a simple example from the links above:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 4):

`bash` doesn't really do threads -- it does do *processes* just fine, though:

```
python whatever.py &
```

the `&` at the end just means "don't wait for the subprocess to end" -- `bash` will execute the command itself in a separate process anyway, it's just that normally it waits for that separate process to terminate (all Unix shells work that way since time immemorial).

Answer (score 2):

Your jargon is all confused. But in bash you can run a process in the **background** by appending a `&`:

```
print foo.py &
```